# How to display Deserialized Data

Tags: xml, vb.net, deserialization

Hi I have an Xml file below that I am able to deserialize.

```
   <datatransfer>
      <start>
        <msgdate>20140416</msgdate>
        <msgtime>112857</msgtime>
      </start>
      <details>
        <ref>test3</ref>
        <accountref>ABC01</accountref>
        <accountfrom />
        <accepted>Y</accepted>
        <requesteddate>20140418</requesteddate>
        <requestedtime>210000</requestedtime>
      </details>
      <end>
        <nbr>1</nbr>
      </end>
    </datatransfer>
```

I am deserializing using the following code

```
    Public Shared Function LoadFromXMLBookingConfirmation(Folder As String)
            Try
        Dim Samples As New List(Of datatransfer)
        Dim Files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Folder) ' File where the Booking confirmation is stored.
        For Each fl In Files

            'Deserialize XML file

            Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(fl)
            Dim i As New datatransfer
            Dim x As New XmlSerializer(i.GetType)
            i = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
            Samples.Add(i)
            objStreamReader.Close()
        Next

        Return Samples
```

Samples has everything from the Xml stored but when I put it into a datagridview I just get the headings "start, details and end" and under each one I have test.start, test.details and test.end.

Here is the code I use to put the data into the datagridview.

```
    DataGridView1.DataSource = test.ControllerClass.LoadFromXMLBookingConfirmation("c:\ftptest\Booking Confirmation")
```

How can I show the all the data in the datagridview?

Comment: show the code for `when I put it into a datagridview` from the looks though, you will have to drill into the datatransfer object or perhaps normalize it.

Comment: Just write a method in the `datatransfer` object to return a `DataTable` representation of the data, then assign this to the `DataGridView.DataSource`.

Comment: I've added the code on how I add it to the datagridview